# Faster iteration

Tags: performance, powershell, foreach, iteration

I have this code, which is part of a function that returns a list of SQL rows based on a time range.

The query itself (1st line of code) is quite fast. But the `foreach` loop that extract the relevant data takes a while to complete.

I have around 350.000 lines to iterate, and despite it's has to take a while, I was wondering if there is any change I could make in order to make it faster.

```
$SqlDocmasterTableResuls = $this.SqlConnection.GetSqlData("SELECT DOCNUM, DOCLOC FROM MHGROUP.DOCMASTER WHERE ENTRYWHEN between '" + $this.FromDate + "' and '" + $this.ToDate + "'")

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ListOfDocuments = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::New()

if ($SqlDocmasterTableResuls.Rows.Count)
{
    foreach ($Row in $SqlDocmasterTableResuls.Rows)
    {
        $DocProperties = @{
            "DOCNUM"      = $Row.DOCNUM
            "SOURCE"      = $Row.DOCLOC
            "DESTINATION" = $Row.DOCLOC -replace ([regex]::Escape($this.iManSourceFileServerName + ":" + $this.iManSourceFileServerPath.ROOTPATH)),
                            ([regex]::Escape($this.iManDestinationFileServerName + ":" + $this.iManDestinationFileServerPath.ROOTPATH))
        }

        $DocObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $DocProperties
        $ListOfDocuments.Add($DocObj)
    }

    return $ListOfDocuments
```

Comment: There is a good chance the SQL query is actually only being executed during the if/foreach statement calls. Have you cheked SQL tracing to see how long the actual SQL query took?

Comment: @Russell the query takes about 10 seconds max... I have already debug the code and it is taking around 5 minutes in the foreach.  tnks

Comment: cool - another thing to check is try removing the 2 lines with regexmatching to eliminate them from causing the delay.

Comment: @Russell I already thought about it but I need this change. I'll still try to remove it to see the result.Tnks

Comment: Well... not much of a difference. Actually it seems exacly the same :(

Comment: This looks scary vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you are absolutely right. I'll change it later. Just testing tnks

Comment: I've never tested it. But I wonder if piping $SqlDocmasterTableResuls.Rows into foreach is faster. Make the first line `$row = $_`

Comment: Far too often "change it later" becomes "change it never".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid appending to an array in a loop. The best way to capture loop data in a variable is to simply collect the loop output in a variable:

```
$ListOfDocuments = foreach ($Row in $SqlDocmasterTableResuls.Rows) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        "DOCNUM"      = $Row.DOCNUM
        "SOURCE"      = $Row.DOCLOC
        "DESTINATION" = $Row.DOCLOC -replace ...
    }
}
```

You don't need the surrounding `if` conditional, because if the table doesn't have any rows the loop should skip right over it, leaving you with an empty result.

Since you want to return the list anyway, you don't even need to collect the loop output in a variable. Just leave the output as it is and it will get returned anyway.

Also avoid repeating operations in a loop when their result doesn't change. Calculate the escaped source and destination paths once before the loop:

```
$srcPath = [regex]::Escape($this.iManSourceFileServerName + ':' + $this.iManSourceFileServerPath.ROOTPATH)
$dstPath = [regex]::Escape($this.iManDestinationFileServerName + ':' + $this.iManDestinationFileServerPath.ROOTPATH)
```

and use the variables `$srcPath` and `$dstPath` inside the loop.

Something like this should do:

```
$SqlDocmasterTableResuls = $this.SqlConnection.GetSqlData("SELECT ...")

$srcPath = [regex]::Escape($this.iManSourceFileServerName + ':' + $this.iManSourceFileServerPath.ROOTPATH)
$dstPath = [regex]::Escape($this.iManDestinationFileServerName + ':' + $this.iManDestinationFileServerPath.ROOTPATH)
foreach ($Row in $SqlDocmasterTableResuls.Rows) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'DOCNUM'      = $Row.DOCNUM
        'SOURCE'      = $Row.DOCLOC
        'DESTINATION' = $Row.DOCLOC -replace $srcPath, $dstPath
    }
}

return
```

Comment: Tnks for the tips. I'll give it a try. But the the regex replace I need to include it in the loop because it is based on the value that comes from the table, it is never the same, it is a file path, that I need to change. something like c:\folder1\file1.txt to d:\folder2\file1.txt. tnks. Ill let you know the result.

Comment: huuuge difference... half the time :) tnks Ansgar.

Comment: oh ... and you were also correct about the $srcPath and $dstPath out of the loop... my mistake.:)

Answer (score 0):

*[edit - per Ansgar Wiechers, the PSCO accelerator is only available with ps3+.]*

one other thing that may help is to replace `New-Object` with `[PSCustomObject]`. that is usually somewhat faster to use. something like this ...

```
$DocObj = [PSCustomObject]$DocProperties
```

another way to use that type accelerator is to do what Ansgar Wiechers did in his code sample, but use the accelerator instead of the cmdlet. like this ...

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    'DOCNUM'      = $Row.DOCNUM
    'SOURCE'      = $Row.DOCLOC
    'DESTINATION' = $Row.DOCLOC -replace $srcPath, $dstPath
    }
```

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: tnks for the tip. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator is not available prior to PowerShell v3.